# Sodium metal in acetone

Tags: redox, metal, carbonyl-compounds

When I place a chunk of 99,99% pure sodium metal in a beaker of (100% chemically pure) acetone, the sodium metal starts reacting and dissolving into the acetone and it forms a yellow/brown liquid. When the acetone evaporates it leaves a dark-brown goo that is like a gel. And it smells like tar or something similar. What is this substance?

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6527/how-does-sodium-in-ethanol-reduce-carbonyl-compounds

Comment: Brown goo is the ultimate product of ***any*** organic reaction. Some reactions happen to produce something useful besides it, some don't.

Answer (score 5):

I can suggest only two possibilities:

1. Your acetone or sodium are not pure. Acetone contains water, or something.
2. Sodium might react [like magnesium does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinacol_coupling_reaction), though it required different conditions. That's possible, but maybe you just discovered a new reaction or had some weird impurities that served as a catalyst.

[image: mechanism]

Comment: Self-condensation of the acetone catalysed by NaOH (formed from trace water) is also a possibility

Comment: I'm not sure if its concentration would be sufficient to cause this rapid condensation

Comment: It only requires a catalytic amount